# C++ SendMessage / PostMessage WM_KEYDOWN WM_KEYUP doesn't work

Tags: c++, sendmessage, postmessage, findwindow

I'm attempting to press the Left arrow key button and Right arrow key button.
The Window Handle I'm passing in is correct. (see screenshot below)

I used Microsoft Spy++ to figure out the correct PostMessage when I press Left/Right keys.

Here are the screenshots showing the `lParam` and `WParam`

First 2 screenshots are `VK_RIGHT` (`WM_KEYDOWN` & `WM_KEYUP`)
Next 2 screenshots are `VK_LEFT` (`WM_KEYDOWN` & `WM_KEYUP`)

[image: postmessage 1]
[image: postmessage 2]
[image: postmessage 3]
[image: postmessage 4]

Here is the code I attempted to use it works by pressing `NUMPAD1,2,3` to test out whether or not the `VK_LEFT` OR `VK_RIGHT` works.. (none of them work).

```
gKey(VK_NUMPAD1) //crap testing
        {
            windowHandle = FindWindow(L"SSClientMainWndClass", NULL);
            printf("window handle = %x\n", windowHandle);
            PostMessage(windowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RIGHT, 0x414D0001);
            //Sleep(1000);
            PostMessage(windowHandle, WM_KEYUP, VK_RIGHT, 0xC14D0001);
            Sleep(1000);

        }
gKey(VK_NUMPAD2) //crap testing
        {
            windowHandle = FindWindow(L"SSClientMainWndClass", NULL);
            printf("window handle = %x\n", windowHandle);
            PostMessage(windowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_LEFT, 0x414B0001);
            Sleep(1000);
            PostMessage(windowHandle, WM_KEYUP, VK_LEFT, 0xC14B0001);
            Sleep(1000);
        }
```

[image: code]

Here are the screenshots of pressing the `VK_NUMPAD1` in the game. (The Post message is sent to the correct Window and the information seems correct!)
[image: [postmessage 1]
[image: postmessage 2]

Comment: If I recall correctly, an antivirus might be blocking the usage of this function to prevent keyloggers. The code appears fine.. Do you have ZoneAlarm, Avira or anything like that?

Comment: What makes you think the target process accepts input of that form. Tell us about the target process. What is it? Is it running at a higher integrity level? Why don't you use the automation interface?

Comment: Have you tried sending `WM_CHAR`?  Generally the `WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP` messages are traslated to `WM_CHAR` by `TranslateMessage` and not processed in the message loop at all.

Comment: You might also have more success with [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: No anti-virus the game does use `DirectDraw` which I assume uses `DirectInput` as well.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I will try `WM_CHAR` Edit: can't figure out the  lParam for VK_RIGHT VK_LEFT for `WM_CHAR`, But trying the same `lParam` as the `WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP` still does nothing. I will try `SendInput`

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/30/423202.aspx). You can fake the message, but you can't fake the other environmental conditions.

Comment: `SendInput` doesn't seem to work, it works on Notepad, but inside the game, those `VK_LEFT` `VK_RIGHT` don't do anything. I also tried `DIKEYBOARD_LEFT` and `DIKEYBOARD_RIGHT` which is suppose to work for DirectInput games but also doesn't work I also looped all examples 1000 times still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to run your program as administrator, you can't send input to a process more elevated than yours. I used `keybd_event()` and it always worked for me, with the mention that Home/End require KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY.

I know this is old, but I was looking for something similar and saw this has no answer.